# reducibility of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is perhaps a very basic problem in Linear Algebra, which concerns the ability to reduce an operator.

An operator $A$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is called ***reducible*** if there exists non-trival decomposition of $V=V_1\oplus V_2$, such that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are both invariant subspaces of $A$.

The question now is **Suppose $V_1$ is an invariant subspace of $A$, can one find an invariant space $V_2$ of $A$, such that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$?**

In general, the answer is negative. But I saw the following result,

**Theorem:** Suppose $V_1$ is an invariant subspace of $A$, the following two statements are equivalent:

1. There exists an invariant subspace $V_2$ of $A$, such that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$;
2. If there exists a polynomial f, such that $f(A)(V)\subset V_1$, then for every $v\in V$, there exists $v_1\in V_1$ satisfying $f(A)v=f(A)v_1$.

Going from 1. to 2. is quite easy. But the reverse is less trivial. I think the difficulty lies in to find a polynomial $f$ so we can start using 2.

Any thought is appreciated.